# Supabase Client Unresponsive in SvelteKit When User is Signed In and Website Loses Focus

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I am facing an issue with SvelteKit and Supabase integration. When there is no user signed in, the Supabase client works as expected, even when the website loses focus or I change the browser tab. However, when there is a signed-in user, the Supabase client initially functions correctly, but upon losing focus or tab change, it becomes unresponsive and fails to send network requests.

I have thoroughly reviewed the official documentation and believe that I have set up the integration correctly. I tested this behavior across different browsers, and the issue persists consistently.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or can offer insights into why the Supabase client might become unresponsive specifically when a user is signed in? I appreciate any guidance on debugging or potential solutions to resolve this issue.

Comment: That sounds unintentional. Could you open an issue on the supabase-js repo for this please? https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues